# Send an e-mail based on Workflow approval status using Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am new to sharepoint. I am using sharepoint 2007. I have a following requirement.

1) Custom list has various fields ... Requestor, Application Name, Reason, etc..

2) When person fill out the form (custom list). It will send a notification to Approvers for review and based on Request action : Approved --> It will send an e-mail notification to specific group.

I have a setup a document approval workflow on custom list.  Workflow works fine but I don't know how to send an e-mail notification based on workflow status : Approved. I have tried to create a another workflow using Sharepoint Designer 2007 but didn't work.

I would like to know whether it is possible without doing any programmatic way ?  I would appreciate your reply.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like a SharePoint Designer Workflow, which responds to actions and rules.

You can get an introduction [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101005871033.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

follow the steps ,these are the main steps you can have a try:

1. Create workflow attach to the list and start it manually & auto
   start it when a new item is created & auto start it when an item is
   modified.

   2. Add Collect data from a User action. Click data and add a choice field (named it approval, give two choices: approve, reject)
      in the custom task wizard.  Output to Variable:collect
   3. Add a new step,  Conditions: if Variable:collect equals to Approve Actions:       Send email to Created by
                    Collect (main manager) data from a user. Output to Variable:collect1(similar with step 2) Conditions: if
      Variable:collect1 equals to Reject Actions:        Send email to
      Created By.
   4. Add new step similar with step 3. Send approve email to Created By when Variable:collect1 equals to Approve or send reject
      email when Varible:collect1 equals to Reject.

here is one of bolg which also you can refer
http://www.gandhipritesh.com/2009/07/create-custom-approval-workflow-using.html